# SharePoint web part connection (SharePoint 2019 classic page)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, web-part, 2019, classic-experience

Is there a way to connect two web parts, but if the Select column is not selected (Send first row to connected Web Parts when page loads turned OFF) to have the connected web part display all ?

So, if no item is selected, show all, if selected only show the selected one. Right now if nothing is selected, then nothing shows on the second web part.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior SharePoint connected web parts.

When you disable the "Send first row to connected Web Parts when page loads" settings from web part, it does not show any items in connected list web part until you select any item in first list web part.

Unfortunately, there is no SharePoint out the box option to allow loading all items when "Send first row to connected Web Parts when page loads" setting is disabled.

Comment: thank you Ganesh